# Negative RGB Values

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I visualize negative RGB values?.
As per OpenCV Documentation:
CV_8S - 8-bit signed integers ( -128..127 )
Does it mean that -128 mean 0 and 127 means 255? 
If yes, then why do we need to have 
CV_8U - 8-bit unsigned integers ( 0..255 )?
I am sorry if my question is trivial.

Comment: *"How do I visualize negative RGB values?"* - However you want. Really, if you got signed numbers in the first place, they are either not representing colors but other data, or they are colors from a different color format than the classical [0,255]-RGB space. So it is entirely up to you to transform those data values into reasonable colors depending on their meaning and your application.

Comment: Signed numbers generally are not used to store RGB values in my experience.  Can you provide a link to the documentation you are referring to?  I would need to see it to understand how they are used.

Comment: `(-128, -128, -128)` would be something you should light with full power to see that it is black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason for 8-bit signed values for pixel calculation comes from the necessity to represent RGB colors in YUV, YCrCb or other modes with chrominance. The Chrominance channels are encoded as differences in Green-Blue and Green-Red or Green-Yellow, Red-Blue etc. to simplify the answer. This range has also negative values.

Answer (score 4):

-1 is the same as 255, -2 is 254, -3 is 253 and so forth - -128 is like 128. The positive numbers are the same - signed an unsigned.

You should read about [signed and unsigned integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: I understand that but how does that apply to RGB values? Gray Scale image has a minimum value of 0 representing black and 255 representing white.Now, in signed representation -128 represents black and 127 represents white. Why do I need to represent grayscale values using signed numbers?

Comment: @Andersonneo *"Now, in signed representation -128 represents black and 127 represents white"* - It seems you got your answer. Since if you know this meaning, you know how to transform them. *"Why do I need to represent grayscale values using signed numbers?"* - That is a question only *you* can answer. So if those are supposed to be greyscale or color values, *why did you use a signed format at all*?